# A set of equations, vertically aligned, individually tagged, with subequations, and separate label

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

Can the following be achieved using just `amsmath` and `mathtools`? (If not, what other tools do I need?)

I have a collection of equations

```
\begin{align}
A &= B \\
C &= D \\
E &= F
\end{align}
```

I want the following display:

1. The three equations are all aligned at the `=` sign (like above)
2. The equation numbers for the first two are "subequations", that is the first equation is numbered (1a), the second (1b), but the third (2). (The numbering should be *dynamical*, I don't want to hard-code an equation number that I'd have to change every time.)
3. Since I am already putting the equation number on the left, I want to group the first two equations and mark them with a brace. Something similar to what can be done with

   ```
   \begin{equation*}
   \left.\begin{aligned}
   A &= B\\
   C &= D
   \end{aligned}\right\}\text{Some description}
   \end{equation*}
   ```

I know how to do each of 1, 2, and 3 separately. I am at a loss on how to put any *two* of them together. I would love to know how to achieve all three at the same time.

*Edit*: To do 1 and 2 together, I can use one of [these answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34566/mixed-subequation-numbering-within-an-array).

*Edit 2*: A partial solution toward doing 1 and 3 together is to use the `empheq` package as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/a-lateral-brace-to-group-a-set-of-equations-with-labels). However best as I can tell the brace is an "all or nothing" thing. I can't just brace the first two out of three expressions.

Answer (score 3):

The following is taken from [Mixed (sub)equation numbering within an array](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34568/5764) (which satisfies 1 & 2), with the addition of grouping via braces (satisfying 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcounter{subeqn} \renewcommand{\thesubeqn}{\theequation\alph{subeqn}}%
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{subeqn}{equation}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\subeqn}{%
  \refstepcounter{subeqn}% Step subequation number
  \tag{\thesubeqn}% Label equation
}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  A + B &\to C + D \\
  E + F &\to G + H \label{eq:EFGH} 
          \smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\normalbaselineskip+.5\jot}{$%
            \left.\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\\[\jot]\\[\jot]\end{array}\right\}\text{Description 1}
          $}}\\
  I + J &\to K + L \refstepcounter{equation}\subeqn \\
        &\to M + N \subeqn \label{eq:MN}
          \smash{\left.\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\\[\jot]\\[\jot]\\[\jot]\end{array}\right\}\text{Description 2}}\\
        &\to O + P \subeqn
\end{align}

The EFGH equation is \eqref{eq:EFGH} and the MN is equation~\eqref{eq:MN}.
\end{document}
```

For grouping an odd number of equations, insert a `\smash`ed `array` in the middle equation. For an even number of equations, insert a `\smash`ed `array` in the equation just below the middle, and move it up `.5\normalbaselineskip+.5\jot`, putting it right in the middle (vertically).

The `array` has a `@{}c@{}` column specification, thereby have width zero. However, the `\nulldelimiterspace` on the left (from `\left.`) pushes it slightly away from the equations. The vertical line skip of `\\[\jot]` within each `array` is to maintain the same vertical height as that of `align`.

Comment: Ooh, this looks promising. I'll give it a try tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: It almost works (except for one minor detail): the line heights of equation/align environments aren't always fixed. For example, if you insert `\int` in front of `A+B` in the first line of the `align`, the vertical size and alignment of the array breaks. `:-(`

Comment: @WillieWong: You'll notice that my "filler" `array` for the right brace `\}` is empty. You could try inserting *the same* content that is visible inside the `align` environment, but hide it with `\vphantom`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
A &= B \\
C &= D \\
E &= F\tag{2}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

Comment: I don't want to hard-code the tag for the third equation (which will require me changing the number every single time the document is changed).

Answer (score 0):

I tried experimenting with the various environments from the `mathtools` package (such as `cases`, `rcases`, etc), but had no success.

If you combine the answers from

- [Mixed (sub)equation numbering within an array](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34566/mixed-subequation-numbering-within-an-array)
- [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570)

Then you can achieve

[image]

which I think (?) is what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% taken from
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34566/mixed-subequation-numbering-within-an-array
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\setcounter{subeqn}{0}}% Reset subequation number at start of align
\newcounter{subeqn} \renewcommand{\thesubeqn}{\theequation\alph{subeqn}}%
\newcommand{\subeqn}{%
  \refstepcounter{subeqn}% Step subequation number
  \tag{\thesubeqn}% Label equation
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% taken from
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node[anchor=base] (#1) {\phantom{1}};}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  A + B &\to C + D \\
  E + F &\to G + H \label{eq:EFGH} \\
  I + J &\to K + L \hfill\tikzmark{right} \refstepcounter{equation}\subeqn \\
        &\to M+N \tikzmark{1st}\subeqn \label{eq:MN}\\
        &\to O + P\tikzmark{2nd} \subeqn
\end{align}


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate,ultra thick,red] 
    (1st.north)--(2nd.south);
 \end{tikzpicture}

The EFGH equation is \eqref{eq:EFGH} and the MN is equation~\eqref{eq:MN}.
\end{document}
```