# How to make an equation system with right brackets on “two levels”

Tags: brackets

does someone know how to make these "double" right brackets? I have not been able to find a solution.

Best,
Tiziano

[image]

Comment: What type of alignment is needed across the equations?

Comment: Related: [A lateral brace to group a set of equations with labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2532/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to [A lateral brace to group a set of equations with labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2532/5764), here is an option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,empheq,amssymb,zref-savepos}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[right={\empheqrbrace\ \forall t \in \mathbb{N}}]{align}
                  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c\zsaveposy{top}
  \raisebox{-.5\dimexpr\zposy{top}sp-\zposy{bot}sp}[0pt][0pt]{$
    \hspace{15pt}\left.\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\zposy{top}sp-\zposy{bot}sp}\right\}\ \forall i \in \mathbb{N}
  $} \\
         ax^2 + bx + c &= g(x)\zsaveposy{bot} \\
                  h(x) &= dx^3 + ex^2 + fx + h \hspace{35pt} \\
  dx^3 + ex^2 + fx + h &= i(x)
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`tikz` can be useful for this task, because the braces are nested such that using `empheq` won't be easy. Using an `overlay` picture, the braces don't interfere with how the equations are laid out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tkzmark}[1]{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\coordinate(#1);}}

\begin{align}
eq1\tkzmark{0} \\
eq2\tkzmark{1}  \\
eq3 \\
eq4
\end{align}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node at ([shift={(.5em,-.5em)}]0)[right] {$\left.\rule{0pt}{1.2\baselineskip}\right\} \forall i \in N$};
\node at ([shift={(5em,-.5em)}]1)[right] {$\left.\rule{0pt}{2.5\baselineskip}\right\} \forall t \in N$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]